# Finding first and last elements in time added to Guava LinkedHashMultimap/HashMultiMap

Tags: java, hashmap, guava

I have a stream of timestamped stats coming for every minute(arbitrary number of stats for each min). It's just an ongoing stream of stats and no change in previous is allowed. Also there is no concurrency issue here. So the appropriate data structure is a `map<timestamp,list<stats>>`. However this map only needs to keep data for last 30 mins so it should also kick out the first element and write the new one(circular buffer). I've been told Guava HashMultimap is a good candidate to use. But I can't figure out how I can use it and find the first and last elements of map and how to delete the last element. When I look at [LinkedHashMultiMap](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/LinkedHashMultiset.html) I don't see any method for finding first or last elements. I appreciate any help.

Comment: I'm going to post an answer, but could you please edit your question to answer the following questions that will change how you implement this. 1. Is concurrent access to the Map/Multimap allowed? 2. Will the list of stats be modified? Or is it only inserted, read, and then removed after 30 minutes?

Comment: In your question, your link points to LinkedHashMultiset but the text states LinkedHashMap. You may want to edit your question to change the text or the link so they match, that confused me yesterday. I tried to edit it myself but I don't think the edit reviewers understood that they didn't match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of approaches you can take. I will explain and show examples of both. I will not address synchronization, if that is necessary let me know and I can add details to ensure the Multimap code is threadsafe. This involves correctly synchronizing on the multimap when accessing its views and wrapping it in a synchronized wrapper. More details can also be found [here](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Multimaps.html#synchronizedListMultimap-com.google.common.collect.ListMultimap-).

1. Use a Multimap
2. Use Guava's [Cache](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/CachesExplained)

For the Multimap approach, I would recommend you use the [LinkedListMultimap](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/LinkedListMultimap.html). It will ensure your keys are ordered and your values are ordered (since you originally stated `Map<Timestamp, List<Stat>>`. A LinkedHashMultimap will preserve the order but it will remove duplicate stats. If this isn't a concern, then you could use LinkedHashMultimap.

To get the first key value, you can use the iterator or use Guava's [Iterables](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html) getFirst(Iteratable, defaultValue) utility method. To get the last key value, you can Iterables getLast(Iteratable, defaultValue) method.
If your goal is just to remove the values older than 30 minutes, you could ignore Iterables and just use the iterator of they Multimap's keys.

```
LinkedHashMultimap<Date, Stat> stats = LinkedHashMultimap.create();

//Every minute
stats.putAll(new Date(), newStats);

//To get the first key inserted into the map
Date first = Iterables.getFirst(stats.keys(), null);
//Remove the first entry
stats.remove(first);

//To get the last key inserted into the map
Date last = Iterables.getLast(stats.keys(), null);
//Remove the last entry
stats.remove(last);

//Without using Iterables.
Set<Date> keys = stats.keys();
if (!keys.isEmpty()) {
    keys.iterator().next().remove();
}
```

The Multimap approach requires you to manually manage removing old stats. A slightly simpler approach in this regard would be to use Guava's Cache. Note, however, that this does not maintain order of any kind and would be more difficult to get the values for a time, since you would not have the exact timestamp of when the stats were inserted. You would need to create your own custom Date class with a `.hashCode()` and `.equals(Object)` method that would work for your needs. This may be more work than it is worth.

```
Cache<CustomDate, List<Stat>> cache = CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
        .expireAfterWrite(30, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
        .build();

cache.put(new CustomDate(), stats);
List<Stat> statsForTime = cache.get(new CustomDate(/*appropriate initialization*/));
```

Comment: Thank you very much it helped a lot!

Comment: I'm happy to help. If this answer or any other one in the future solved your issue, you can mark it as accepted as a way to say thanks.